# propel generated peer and query filename

Tags: php, codeigniter, propel, peer

I added propel library in my codeigniter project
Codeigniter 2.1.3 Propel 1.6.7
but apparently as propel users know it generates camelcase names

ex. UsersQuery.php UsersPeer.php

but codeigniter wont accept camelcase names when executing

```
$this->load->model('UsersQuery');
```

does anyone know how to change generated propel model class to lowercase filenames?
because if i will just rename each file, i will do it everytime i generate classes and it's not efficient.

Answer (score 0):

I think i got it but not tested 100%

I've search all the text on my project that contains 'Peer' and 'Query' and replaced the first letter with small.

Search are done using case sensitive approach to match exactly the strings.

If i recall there are at least less than 7 matches on each of the word. (not sure)

but there is a string that look like this 'Peer:: (quotes are included) and i also changed the first letter of it to small one (i just changed need but i don't know if it will affect the program, hope someone can clarify this.)

but when i test to run the generated scripts:
propel-gen om
propel-gen sql
propel-gen insert-sql
propel-gen

and try to load the models and use it,

luckily there's no error.. :P

Answer (score 0):

[Add these lines](http://propelorm.org/documentation/02-buildtime.html#setting-up-propel) to your `index.php`, works perfectly for me.

```
<?php
// Include the main Propel script
require_once '/path/to/propel/runtime/lib/Propel.php';

// Initialize Propel with the runtime configuration
Propel::init("/path/to/bookstore/build/conf/bookstore-conf.php");

// Add the generated 'classes' directory to the include path
set_include_path("/path/to/bookstore/build/classes" . PATH_SEPARATOR . get_include_path());
```

Then just call UsersQuery and UsersPeer as you would normally in PHP, no includes necessary :D.

And make sure none of your controllers/models are named the same as your Propel classes.